Why is Hann windowing identical to convolution with [-1/4, 1/2, -1/4] in the spectral domain?
I'm trying to understand why multiplying by a Hann window in the time domain corresponds to convolving with the kernel [-1/4, 1/2, 1/4]. I've put together the following chain of reasoning, but I have some questions throughout and at the end (which I've put in bold).
Let's say we have an input signal x(t) with FT X(w) (where w is the frequency bin index).

The FFT of the Hann window is the the sum of 3 sinc functions, where the first is centered at 0 and the other two are scaled by 0.5 shifted over by one frequency bin to the left and right respectively (picture here - does this mean that FT of the Hann window purely real? and why is this picture different than the FT on the Wikipedia page for Hann function?)
Thus, multiplying x(t) by Hann in time domain <=> convolving X(w) with the FT of Hann in frequency domain <=> convolving X(w) with the sum of those 3 sinc functions
Convolution is distributive, so multiplying by Hann in time domain <=> convolution(X(w), sinc1) + convolution(X(w), sinc2) + convolution(X(w), sinc3)
Convolution with a sinc function just gives you back the function itself (up to a scaling constant which seems to be 1/2 here - I don't fully understand this part; I thought it was 1/pi. Is that a difference between continuous/discrete cases?)
Thus convolution(X(w), sinc1) + convolution(X(w), sinc2) + convolution(X(w), sinc3) = 0.5X(w) + 0.25X(w+1) + 0.25X(w-1)
So then the Hann windowed version of X(w) (which is in frequency domain) is just 0.5X(w) + 0.25X(w+1) + 0.25X(w-1) which ALMOST aligns with this article along with other stack exchange articles like this.
The difference is that instead of adding the 0.25 terms, you subtract them. Why is that?


a) please give an exact definition and  reference for your initial assertion (which I think is not correct as written). b) you seem to mix discrete and continuous domains quite a bit. I strongly suggest picking one domain staying in there until you have fully worked it out. Then proceed to the other.

If you deal with window functions having even symmetry, your life gets a lot easier.  At least in theory.  Once you move the problem to MATLAB, they just don't like them negative indices.  Anyway it should be $[\tfrac14, \tfrac12, \tfrac14]$.  No minus sign.

Bottom Line
I'll answer the questions in bold first but then provide further necessary details below.

does this mean that FT of the Hann window purely real?

If the Hann window is non-causally centered symmetrically on $n=0$ in the time domain (with $n$ as units of time in samples), then the Fourier Transform will be real. Any symmetric even waveforms in the time domain will be real (zero-phase) in the frequency domain. The window can be applied as such or can be delayed in time to be causal, which would then add a negative linear phase in the frequency domain.

which seems to be 1/2 here - I don't fully understand this part; I
thought it was 1/pi. Is that a difference between continuous/discrete
cases?

In the continuous time case the resulting coefficients are convolved with a Sinc function given Hann function as $0.5+0.5cos(2\pi f/T)$ is multiplied with a rectangular window in time extending from $-T/2$ to $+T/2$.
In the discrete time it is nearly the same, but to be accurate the resulting coefficients are convolved with the Dirichlet Kernel, which is essentially an aliased Sinc function due to the sampling process.

The difference is that instead of adding the 0.25 terms, you subtract
them. Why is that?

If it the Hann Window is non-causal centered on zero, the function is described by $x(t)= 0.5 + 0.5 cos(t/T)$ with $-T/2 \le t<T/2$ and therefore the coefficients as given by the Fourier Transform are $[0.25, 0.5, 0.25]$. If the Hann  window is shifted in time by $T/2$ sufficient to be causal, the function is described by $x(t) = 0.5 - 0.5 cos(t/T)$ with $0 \le t < T$ and the coefficients in that case are given by the Fourier Transform as $[-0.25, 0.5, -0.25]$. In both cases these coefficients are convolved with a Sinc function (if continuous time as described here), which does not change their value at the frequencies given as [-1/T, 0, +1/T], but serves to interpolate the result as a continuous function in frequency.
For further details and insights, see below.
Detailed Answer with further insights
The continuous time Hann window is given as:
$$x(t) = 0.5 - 0.5\cos(2\pi f/T), 0 \le t < T$$
In discrete time, the Hann window is $x(t)$ sampled symmetrically as follows
$$x[n] = 0.5 - 0.5 \cos(2 \pi n/(N-1)), \space\space n = 0,1,2,\ldots N-1$$
With the DFT and DTFT results as plotted below. The DFT result is consistent with convolving with [-0.25, 0.5, -0.25] (nearly) but windowing with the Hann would be identical to convolving with the DTFT which is the continuous function plotted in the frequency domain below.
The DFT plotted is the normalized DFT as:
$$X[n] = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n] e^{j2\pi n k/N}$$
And similarly the DTFT plotted here is as follows with $k$ as a continuous function of frequency:
$$X(k) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n] e^{j2\pi n k/N}$$

Note how I plotted both the magnitude and phase. The phase is likely the reason for the confusion on the sign of the coefficients. The convolution with the Sinc (or specifically the Dirichlet Kernel for the discrete time solution) simply serves to interpolate a continuous function between the discrete samples given by the DFT, so we can determine the correct sign of the DFT coefficients and consider the Sinc after. It is the slope of the phase response that is a result of the time delay when we consider the window to start at time $n=0$. A delay in time is a negative linear phase in frequency, and we see how that wrapped phase results in changing the sign of the coefficients whose magnitudes are each 0.25. If we were instead to consider the non-causal window centered on $n=0$, which mathematically is then $0.5 + 0.5cos()$ function instead of the $0.5 - 0.5cos()$ function, then the phase would be zero at all frequencies and the coefficients would be given as [0.25, 0.5, 0.25].
Since the function was sampled symmetrically (instead of $0.5-0.5\cos(2\pi n/N)$ which would represent exact DFT coefficients) there are additional non-zero terms in the other DFT coefficients that are barely visible in the plot. Notably we see the result of the DFT is very close to [-0.25, 0.5, -0.25] when you consider both the magnitude and phase (phase close to $\pi$ for the first and third coefficient which is a sign change).
It is easier to predict the resulting frequency domain result by first centering the waveform on $n=0$ and then use the Fourier time delay property to delay it by $(N-1)/2$ samples.
For example I will demonstrate this with a continuous time Hann window:
Time centered Hann window:
$$x_1(t) = 0.5 + 0.5 \cos(2\pi f/T),  -T/2 \le t < T/2$$
After delay of half the window duration:
$$x_2(t) = x_1(t-T/2) = 0.5 - 0.5\cos(2\pi f/T), 0 \le t < T$$
Consider the Fourier Transform for $x_2(t)$ based on that for $x_1(t)$ with the Fourier time delay property:
$$X_2(f) = X_1(f)e^{-j2\pi f (T/2)} = X_1(f)e^{-j\pi f T}$$
The coefficients for $X_1(f)$ are $[0.25, 0.5, 0.25]$ occurring at frequencies $[-1/T, 0 +1/T]$.
Note how the time delay at the frequencies $-1/T$ and $1/T$ result in a sign change for those frequencies!
For $f=-1/T$:
$$e^{-j\pi f T} = e^{j\pi} = -1$$
And similarly for $f=1/T$.
Thus the coefficients are $[-0.25, 0.5, -0.25]$ and then convolved with the Dirichlet Kernel due to the finite duration from $0$ to $T$ as demonstrated in the actual DFT and DTFT plots above.
Doing the same in discrete time:
$$x_1[n] = 0.5 - 0.5 \cos(2 \pi n/(N-1)), \space\space n = 0,1,2,\ldots N-1$$
Consider the time centered variant (with n in steps of 1, either integers or half-integers depending on $N$ being odd or even):
$$x_2[n] = 0.5 + 0.5 \cos(2 \pi n/(N-1)), \space\space n =-(N-1)/2 \ldots (N-1)/2$$
$$x_1[n] = x_2\bigg[n-\frac{N-1}{2}\bigg]$$
Using the time shift property of the DFT: $x[n-m] \leftrightarrow X[k]e^{-j2\pi m k}$:
$$X_1[k] = X_2[k]e^{-j2\pi k (N-1)/2} = X_2[k]e^{-j\pi k (N-1)}$$
The coefficients will be at $k=0$, $k=1$ and $k=N-1$, and thus we see how the sign for the coefficients at $k=1$ and $k=N-1$ are similarly negated.

Thanks very much all! I'm definitely a bit out of my depth here, but I'll try to tackle this bit by bit. First off, I think I need a better of understanding of what it means to say "the coefficients as given by the Fourier Transform are [0.25,0.5,0.25]." Is this "shorthand" (that is, shorthand which indicates how we will use this function as a kernel) which means that the DFT of the window function is 0.25delta(k+1) + 0.5delta(k) + 0.25delta(k-1), as Baddioes described? And then would you get the DTFT version you plotted when you convolve this sum of deltas with a Sinc/Dirichlet?

Yes the coefficients refer to the DFT values and you can get the DTFT I described by convolving with a Dirichlet Kernel but the easier way is to zero pad the time domain waveform prior to computing the DFT (if you make the waveform 10x longer by adding zeros, it will result in 9 more samples interpolated in frequency between each of the DFT values we would get if it wasn’t zero padded, and those interpolated values are consistent with what you would get if you convolved with a Dirichlet Kernel.

Got it, thanks! Another question: in the frequency domain, we can apply the causal Hann window by convolving with [-0.25, 0.5, -0.25], or the non-causal window by convolving with [0.25, 0.5, 0.25]. In the time domain, we can apply the causal window by multiplying by the causal version of the function sampled from 0 to N. But how would we apply the noncausal window in the time domain?

@empty-inch looks like you are thinking about everything correctly! We see that either way causal or non-causal that we need to align our data with the window. So if you want to use a non-causal window (in post-processing where we can do that) you will need to advance your data (if causal) to be aligned with the window. Or align the window with the data. Either way the math will work out as long as you are consistent

Thanks for all your help! Final question - if we take a causal time series of length N, DFT it, convolve with [0.25, 0.5, 0.25], then IDFT it, will we end up with a non-causal time series which starts in negative time and ends in positive time (in sample indices, it goes from -N/2 to N/2)?

Hi @empty-inch - that is a new question; please accept one of these two answers (whichever one you feel answered your question as posted) to close this out and then post your new question along with the explanation as to what you think it should be or where you are stuck in determining that yourself - thanks! (We’re supposed to avoid long back and forth discussion in the comments as it will soon flag the moderators)


The FFT of the Hann window is the the sum of 3 sinc functions, where the first is centered at 0 and the other two are scaled by 0.5 shifted over by one frequency bin to the left and right respectively

I think you need to check this again. It shouldn't be sinc functions, but Kronecker deltas (in discrete land).

Thus, multiplying x(t) by Hann in time domain <=> convolving X(w) with the FT of Hann in frequency domain

Yes, windowing and FIR filtering have a Fourier relationship.
Questions 3-5 are still dependent on the idea you are convolving with sinc functions, which you aren't. Work it out again with deltas.

So then the Hann windowed version of X(w) (which is in frequency domain) is just 0.5X(w) + 0.25X(w+1) + 0.25X(w-1) which ALMOST aligns with this article along with other stack exchange articles like this. The difference is that instead of adding the 0.25 terms, you subtract them. Why is that?

I think you have the formula for a Hanning window wrong. The formula is
\begin{equation}
w[n] = 0.5\left[1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{N}\right)\right]
\end{equation}
What you are discovering is a property of all raised cosine windows. The form
\begin{equation}
\beta-\frac{1-\beta}{2}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{N}\right)
\end{equation}
has the Fourier transform
\begin{equation}
\beta\delta(k)-\frac{1-\beta}{2}\left[\delta(k-1)+\delta(k+1)\right]
\end{equation}
In a Hanning window, $\beta = 0.5$. For a Hamming window, $\beta = 0.54$. This can be written more generally as
\begin{equation}
\alpha-\frac{\beta}{2}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi n}{N}\right)
\end{equation}
If we compute the sample PSD of a windowed $y[n]$ with the above form, we get
\begin{equation}
\phi_{y}(k) = \frac{1}{N}\left\lvert\alpha Y(k) - \frac{\beta}{2}\left[Y(k-1) + Y(k+1)\right]\right\rvert^{2}
\end{equation}
This leads to an interesting optimization problem in which we can adaptively window, also known as "apodization" (I'll adapt an abbreviated version from [2]). Let our window be $w[n]$. We wish to minimize $\phi_{y}(k)$ subject to $w[n] \geq 0$ and
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w[n] = 1
\end{equation}
which means we are minimizing
\begin{equation}
\left\lvert\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w[n]y[n]e^{-j\omega n}\right\rvert^{2}
\end{equation}
subject to the above constraints. The above constraints are met if $\alpha = 1$ and $0\leq\beta\leq 1$. So, we then wish to solve
\begin{equation}
\min_{\beta\in\left[0,1\right]}\frac{1}{N}\left\lvert Y(k) - \frac{\beta}{2}\left[Y(k-1) + Y(k+1)\right]\right\rvert^{2}
\end{equation}
the solution of which is given by
\begin{equation}
\gamma = \text{Re}\left[\frac{2Y(k)}{Y(k-1)+Y(k+1)}\right]
\end{equation}
So, we then use
\begin{equation}
\beta = 
\begin{cases}
0, & \gamma < 0 \\ \gamma, & 0 \leq \gamma \leq 1 \\ 1, & \gamma > 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here are some pictures to show the differences.

[2] Stoica, P., & Moses, R. L. (2005). Spectral analysis of signals (Vol. 452, pp. 25-26). Upper Saddle River, NJ: Pearson Prentice Hall.

Thanks! Is the top row of plots the PSD of a signal with a peak at 550Hz and then the PSD of the same signal with various windowing functions applied? Is this also what the orange plot in the Hann Function Wikipedia page is of - the PSD/magnitude of the FT of some unpictured input signal with Hann windowing? I thought it was the PSD/mags of the Hann itself, but it's clearly not the sum of three deltas/sincs. But then everywhere I look say the FT mags of Hann looks like that (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.windows.hann.html) - not like the sum of deltas/sincs.

@empty-inch They are all plots of a single complex exponential that is aperiodic to produce spectral leakage. The top row has no noise added, the bottom row has noise added. The sidelobes in the FT magnitude plots, like in the link you provided, come from zero-padding the FFT of the Hanning window, making it aperiodic. If you don't zero-pad, you will get monotonically decreasing sidelobes. There will always be sidelobes because it's not actually a cosine function, defined from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but is a finite-length, discrete approximation of one. We use the delta approximation though.

@empty-inch I should say, for the hanning window, you will get monotonically decreasing sidelobes. That is not necessarily the case for other windows, but is for Hanning windows

Thanks! So to be clear, the second plot from the left in the top row in your answer is the FT magnitude of an aperiodic complex exponential that has had a Hanning window applied. But, in contrast, the plots in the  scipy documentation + the Hann function wikipedia page are of the FT magnitude of the Hanning window itself (NOT applied to a signal) with zeros appended. Is that correct?

And then you’re saying that we approximate the FT magnitude of the Hanning window itself as being the sum of three deltas when we want to apply the window by convolving in the spectral domain rather than multiplying in the time domain, is that correct? I assume the reason we make this approximation is just to make for easier/quicker computations. But why CAN we make this approximation? Because this is what the FT magnitudes would be if it were an infinite, periodic signal?

@empty-inch To your first comment, yes. To your second comment, if you aren’t doing adaptive windowing, you would just multiply in the time domain. And the sum of three Kronecker deltas is exact because the cosine function used is periodic in the DFT window, so there’s no leakage. It’s not periodic if you zero-pad. So, the three Kronecker deltas isn’t an approximation, it is exact.

Ahhh I see now, it all just clicked for me. Thanks so much for all your help!
